# How do I install Netatalk in Ubuntu 9.10 (tutorial)?

Tags: command-line, installation, ubuntu-9.10, netatalk

I have never installed Netatalk before. I have to help someone get this up and running on a Ubuntu 9.10 server and I don't know if there is any special configuration or install steps I need to follow in Ubuntu 9.10 to get it up and running.

I know in older versions of Ubuntu, specifically, special OS changes and configuration needs to be done in order to get it to work properly. Do I need to work around any of those issues in 9.10?

I am doing this remotely through ssh, so I prefer instruction via command-line. Thanks!

Comment: installing is easy: *"sudo aptitude install netatalk"* .. that gets the daemon and utilities; no idea how it's configured tho.

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the first results on Google: [Netatalk](http://www.anders.com/projects/netatalk/)

> Netatalk is a package that lets a Unix machine supply Appletalk print and file services on a LAN. The package supports AppleShare IP and classic Appletalk protocols. With netatalk, Macintosh computers can mount Unix volumes and print to Unix print spools as if they were standard Appletalk network devices.

Comment: it's nice to include some highlights from the material you link to in your answer, instead of just a link.  see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: This doesn't seem to be geared toward anything specific. Which is why I specifically asked about the installation in Ubuntu 9.10.